# How to fetch data from the file and print it on a browser?

Tags: file, go

In this code, I made a function called `viewHandler` in which I made the text area plus I am getting the data from a file that is present in the working directory but when I run this code and check the browser, it just shows me the Editing with a text area and submits button. Although I wrote to print the title and body from the file also but it is not fetching data from there.

**Given result**

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGqjx.png)

```
type Page struct {
    Title string
    Body  []byte
}

func loadPage(title string) (*Page, error) {
    filename := title + ".txt"
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &Page{Title: title, Body: body}, nil
}

func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    title := r.URL.Path[len("/edit/"):]
    p, err := loadPage(title)
    if err != nil {
        p = &Page{Title: title}
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Editing %s</h1>"+
        "<form action=\"/save/%s\" method=\"POST\">"+
        "<textarea name=\"body\">%s</textarea><br>"+
        "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Save\">"+
        "</form>",
        p.Title, p.Title, p.Body)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/view/", viewHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: how do you call this page?

Comment: I followed the step by step process from here https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/

Comment: Why do you have `title := r.URL.Path[len("/edit/"):]` if the page url is `/view/` ?

Comment: i updated the photo. You can see the result

Comment: You're missing the filename in the URL

Comment: I also added the filename but still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url should be something like `http://localhost:8080/view/something` and this will import a file named `something.txt`.

Make sure the file exists in the same folder as the executable and has read permissions.

Comment: I also added the filename but still the same result.